# multiple PDF set header

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this in a loop but I have multiple files that I'd like to generate. I'm receiving `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

If I have one key, then it's fine. If I have more than one, it generates the second one, doesn't generate the first one and gives this error.

```
  _.forEach(keys, async function(key) {
    try {
      const pdf = await myPDFd(key);

      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + key + '.pdf');
      res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
      res.send(pdf);
      res.end();
    } catch (error) {
    }
  });
```

Comment: The problem is that you can't send two responses to one request (`res.send` is sending the response on every loop step). Maybe you could compress the files and then send the response.

Comment: @ArielAlvarado is there a way to stop the response after one pdf is send? I thought `res.end` would do so and create a new one on the next one?

Comment: You cannot initiate the second connection. Server cannot initiate connection to client (not by HTTP). Second connection initialization must comes from client to server (same way as a first connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is not possible.

Each HTTP request responses exactly 1 type of data (one PDF file in your case). Not possible to send 2 files via 1 HTTP request.

You have to create some logic on client (two download links, for example). Client (user or app) must perform two separate actions (run two separate HTTP requests) for 2 files downloading.

Alternatively you can compress this two files to ZIP (or another package type) and send this one ZIP file to user. But in this case user (or app) will have to uncompress it as additional step. You can use [node-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip) library.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do the zip but just curious, I thought `res.end()` would end the request in the loop and restart on the next?

Comment: `res.end()` will completely close the connection. No additional data can be send after call `res.end()` and there is no possibility to reopen closed connection by `res.end()`. When you close the connection, the TCP HTTP connection is finished and since this time the client does not know, that you are doing any additional commands on the server.